# Import new Android Design Support library

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-design-library, android-support-design

Hi i'am trying to import the new android support library like this `com.android.support:support-design:22.0.0` but i got this error after sync the gradle : `failed to find`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to update your Android Support Repository in SDK Manager, then just add this dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

`com.android.support:support-design:22.0.0` is wrong.

Comment: using this implementation I get this problem:
Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX...

Comment: @ladytoky0 This answer was posted 8 years ago.

Answer (score 6):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

New Android Design Libraries usually start with androidx word, such as:

> AppCompat androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

> CardViex androidx:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

> However be careful because everything is not start with ***androidx***. For example, old *design* *dependency* is:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

> But new *design* *dependency* is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

> Recyclerview dependency is:

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
```

So, you have to search and read carefully.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) has it wrong.

It should actually be `'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

as mentioned in their official [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Answer (score 2):

With gradle 3 it should be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I built a complete example. I hope it helps! https://github.com/erikcaffrey/AndroidDesignSupportLibrary

Remember now is available!

[Android Support Library, revision 22.2.1 (July 2015)](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

***ctrl+alt+shift+s*** in the androidstudio window... 
***project structure*** window will appear..
click the ***app*** in the menu bar at the left then click ***dependencies***..
then add `com.android.support:design:26.1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

---

Click on 'File' --> 'Project Structure' (or CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S) --> Select 'Dependencies' --> Click on '+' in the 'All Dependencies' section --> Select '1.Library Dependency'--> here you can search for any library to implement in your android studio project.

Answer (score 1):

i was facing the same problem actually this is old one.
Just replace it with the following code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: to give more context for this answer: support libs are deprecated by now and replaced with AndroidX libs https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library.  this is the replacement for the design lib it was renamed to material