# Change background color each item of menu

Tags: android, menu

I want create menu like this image.

[image]

I want this menu to appear after clicking on a button.

Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item

            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:id="@+id/fromFirstMonth"
            android:title="از ابتدای سال"
            android:drawable="@drawable/nav_item_background"/>
        <item
            android:state_pressed="true"
            android:id="@+id/currentMonth"
            android:title="این ماه"
            android:drawable="@color/blueMenu"/>
        <item
            xmlns:showAsAction="always"
            android:id="@+id/currentSession"
            android:title="این فصل"

            android:drawable="@color/white"/>
        <item
            xmlns:showAsAction="always"
            android:id="@+id/selection"
            android:title="تانتخابی"
            android:drawable="@color/blueMenu"/>

</menu>
```

I have tried to set a different color for each item but it does not seem to be working.

Is there a way to have the background color for each menu item alternate like the image above?

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498332/pop-menu-items-with-different-color/36499063#36499063

Answer (score 0):

Try `app:itemBackground="@color/blueMenu"` instead of `android:drawable="@color/blueMenu"/>`

If you have trouble with "app" add this at the beginning:

`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: i change to  `app:itemBackground` but still not worked. and say error Error:(5) No resource identifier found for attribute 'itemBackground' in package 'hitesh.sazyar'

Comment: Did you include `com.android.support:design` library?

Comment: where i should include `com.android.support:design`?

Comment: In your gradle file under the dependencies section. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543098/import-new-android-design-support-library